# Can I really make a function like macro

Tags: c, macros

Here is an example:

```
#define get_i() i
int i;
int i2;
```

`i2 = get_i();`

In the case above ^^^ `get_i()` acts like a function that returns something(the value of`i` in this case).

```
#define set_i(value)  do{i = (value);}while(0)
set_i(i2);
```

This ^^^ above acts like a function that DO NOT return.

My question is, can I use macros to create a function-like macro that can both, do something, and return an object? Here is a pseudo code:

```
#define increse_i2_and_return_i()  i2++; return i;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: use the comma operator. but better, tell us *what* you're trying to accomplish (and not how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use comma operator for that. The value of the last operand will be the value of an entire expression.

```
#define increse_i2_and_return_i() (i2++, i)
```

The downside of this trick is that you can't create temporary variables in a such macro.

Comment: I will pass the variables, as arguments. This is exactly what I was serchig for ;)